# Changes to cookie domain for outgoing responses ignored for ServiceStack requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, servicestack, forms-authentication

I have a multi-tenant website (e.g. several different sites, each with it's own domain, all in the same project, separated using MVC areas), where the authentication cookie has the domain manually set when the user logs in so that it is available to all subdomains (but not the various other sites in the project, this is *not* an SSO).

So a user logins a x.foo.com, the cookie domain is set for foo.com, so that it also works at y.foo.com and z.foo.com. However, because of the other domains being served from the same project the auth cookie domain cannot be set in the web.config in the usual manner, instead it is set manually when the user logins in like so:

```
public HttpCookie GetAuthenticationCookie(string username)
{
    var cookieDomain = UrlHelper.GetTopAndSecondLevelDomain();
    var authenticationCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);
    authenticationCookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
    return authenticationCookie;
}
```

This works fine, but of course can cause a problem when the cookie is automatically refreshed for sliding expiration. So we have an HTTP module which is hooked into the `PostRequestHandlerExecute` event of our MVC app to look for auth cookies that were set into the response during the request, and overriding the domain:

```
public class AuthenticationCookieDomainInterceptorModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += UpdateAuthenticationCookieExpiry;
    }

    private void UpdateAuthenticationCookieExpiry(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
        var cookieDomain = UrlHelper.GetTopAndSecondLevelDomain();

        var authenticationCookie = GetCookieFromResponse(app.Context.Response, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

        if (authenticationCookie != null)
        {
            if (authenticationCookie.Domain == null || !string.Equals(authenticationCookie.Domain, cookieDomain, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                authenticationCookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
            }
        }
    }

    private HttpCookie GetCookieFromResponse(HttpResponse response, string cookieName)
    {
        var cookies = response.Cookies;
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.Count; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].Name == cookieName)
            {
                return cookies[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

This is also works fine *unless* the request is to our ServiceStack front end which we use to handle our AJAX requests. In that case the module fires as normal, picks up the cookie if its been set, changes the domain as it should, but when the response is sent back to the client the changes to the cookie are ignored.

Is there any reason why the cookie changes wouldn't be saved to the response in this scenario? My guess would be something to do with the fact ServiceStack uses an HttpHandler to hook in the request cycle in the first place, so we are not going through the normal MVC request life-cycle.